Why Spring Data Jpa can't delete do cascade remove?
I have this repository:
public interface CheckListRepository extends BaseRepository<CheckList, Long>,  JpaSpecificationExecutor<CheckList> {  

  void deleteAllByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
}

And entity Checklist where I have relation between tables
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "checkList", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Category> categories;


I was trying to delete some checklists by their ids in method
@Transactional
    public Response deleteAllCheckLists(BatchChecklistDeleteRequest request) {
        Project currentProject = projectRepository.findByIdOrThrowException(request.getProjectId());
        entityAccessCheck.checkCurrentAccountAccess(currentProject);
        checkListRepository.deleteAllByIdIn(request.getChecklistIds());
        log.info("Deleted checklists with IDs: {}", request.getChecklistIds());
        return new Response<>().deleteAll();
    }

Objects in the database are not deleted
But the request is not even created, I understand that it's about the reference key, but why does everything work as it should with a single deletion request, via a regular deleteById?
An entity without any connections is deleted normally

AFAIK the database is responsible to remove on cascade. Configure the database foreign-key for the remove-cascade.
